# Why does g++ warn about returning a reference to a temporary

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

I have the following code:

```
constexpr const_reference_t at(size_t p_pos) const
{
    using namespace std;

    return (p_pos > m_size)
        ? throw out_of_range{ string{ "string_view_t::at: pos > size() with pos = " } + to_string(p_pos) }
        : m_begin_ptr[p_pos];
}
```

While compiling, g++ is telling me:

/home/martin/Projekte/pluto/pluto-lib/stringview.hpp:50: Warnung: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
             : m_begin_ptr[p_pos];
                                ^
m_begin_ptr is:

```
const_pointer_t m_begin_ptr = nullptr;
```

and const_pointer_t is of type const char*

Is this code really incorrect or is it a false warning? If g++ is correct, why is this a temporary then? And finally, how could I avoid this warning.

g++ version is 7.2.0

I minimized the code further:

```
static const char* greeting = "hallo, world!";

const char& nth(unsigned n)
{
    return true ? throw "" : greeting[n];
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's some serious abuse of the ternary operator you've got there. Use a regular `if` conditional to maintain sanity.

Comment: Returning a reference (or pointer) to a temporary means that the caller receives a reference to an object that no longer exists.   If the caller users that reference, the behaviour is undefined.   Using a throw expression in a ternary expression gives a default-initialised result of the same type as the other expression - which will be uninitialised

Comment: Could you provide a  [mcve]?

Comment: What is `const_reference_t`?

Comment: I added a minimal example without any aliases. const_reference_t is const char&.

Comment: @MartinKalbfuß "minimal complete verifiable example" means something we can compile without having to guess at all. A complete program. Not a snippet.

Comment: I added an empty main function. Now it is not only minimal but complete an verifiable ;-).

Comment: Keep in mind that the ternary operator has to adjust the types of its second and third arguments to some common type. What is the type of `throw ""`? What is the type of `greeting[n]`? What is their common type? How does that relate to the declared return type of the function? Why does the code use a ternary operator in the first place? It's much simpler to use `if ... else` because you don't have to puzzle over some of those questions.

Answer (score 1):

When `(p_pos > m_size)` condition is `true`, you return object created by  [throw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) which according to documentation creates temporary object.

> The exception object is a temporary object in unspecified storage that is constructed by the throw expression.

Because the function return type is `const char&`, which is reference, compiler is trying to cast temporary object to reference, so you get the warning.

You shouldn't try to return result of `throw`, you just only `throw`.

I would personally change ternary operator part to:

```
if (p_pos > m_size) {
    // throw
}
return m_begin_ptr[p_pos];
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But one last Question before I accept this answer. Why does the compiler says: Warnung: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr] : m_begin_ptr[p_pos]. This is the second branch.

Comment: I am not sure about this, maybe someone else? I personally get quite often GCC warnings which doesn't say anything about what caused the original problem, instead GCC complains about some problem, which occur thank's to consequences of original problem. So you should be aware, that problem description from GCC isn't always 100% precise.